# Is there a way to get SpEL to treat a bean that is an implementation of a Functional Interface as a method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, functional-interface

I am creating beans that are implementations of a functional interface, for example:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FooRunnable {
    abstract Bar run();
}
```

I've created a bean with this interface.

I can use SpEL to call the method run() of the bean using, say, the header-enricher:

```xml
   <si:header name="bar" value="@foo.run()" />
```

Is there a way for SpEL to recognize that this is a functional interface and allow me to write simply the following, hence eliminate the method name?

```xml
   <si:header name="bar" value="@foo()" />
```

Thanks for any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; nothing like that is supported.